# Ethernet LAN network prevents wifi from internet access on linux mint

Tags: ethernet

I have ethernet cable LAN and wifi configured on separate LAN networks but they won't work when both are connected on my laptop. I have to disconnect one for the other to work.

NB: There is no IP conflict, I have the ethernet LAN on XX.XX.10.1 and wifi on XX.XX.1.101. I have searched for the solution but all i can find is about connection sharing. What could be the issue? Pointers in the right direction very much appreciated and I'll take it up from there.

Comment: How do you know they don't work at the same time, what have you done to verify this? If they really don't, the issue might be with the system service you use, some can't handle connections on two devices in parallel. Find out which system service handles network connection for you - is it NetworkManager, Wicd, something else?

Comment: I'm using network manager and when i'm on wifi and i plug in the LAN cable, internet connection over wifi stops working and when i unplug the cable, it comes back on.

Comment: Is your IP assignment on the wired network done by DHCP? Or did you manually configure an IP address and gateway? It sounds like the wired network is just misconfigured.

Comment: Actually, it was a misconfiguration. One of the several virtual interfaces i had created for the vlans was conflicting with what the wifi router was giving my wifi card and since i'm experimenting (and learning) about vlans it took me quite a while to wrap my head around it properly enough to do a proper diagnosis. I'll accept this. It gave provided the basis step for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network Manager generally doesn't have problem maintaining connection on multiple devices at same time. At least not in my experience. The problem might be elsewhere. Check the following:

- The configuration of the wired network. `XX.XX.10.1` doesn't look like something assigned by DHCP server, is this network setup correctly? Is it configured as local connection only without internet access? Naturally you can't use both connections for Internet at same time, one will have to take priority and Network Manager will probably prefer the wired one.
- When *internet connection over wifi stops working*, do you mean it gets disconnected in Network Manager or do you just lose internet access? What is in your routing table when this happens (show us output of `ip route` ) - is the default route still over the wireless interface IP?

Alternatively, if you want this resolved without much investigation, you can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15180077/6350644) Network Manager's control over the wired interface and enable `systemd-networkd.service` for it instead. Good guide for this service is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd). (Don't use `systemd-resolved.service` though!)

Comment: I've managed to finally pinpoint the source of the problem (though i can't explain it). I had created a vlan on the ethernet port so when i plugged in the cable, the machine joined that vlan automatically. But what i still don't get is why the wifi stops woking. It remains connected, but no site will load. Even my local site on apache.

Comment: @Dudus sounds like routing problem. I'm afraid i can't explain it either unless i see your routing table before you plug in the ethernet and after you do it (when the wireless stops loading sites). Please add both states to the question.

Comment: Actually, it was a misconfiguration. One of the several virtual interfaces i had created for the vlans was conflicting with what the wifi router was giving my wifi card and since i'm experimenting (and learning) about vlans it took me quite a while to wrap my head around it properly enough to do a proper diagnosis. I'll accept this. It gave provided the basis step for my solution.